# IDisposable - what to Dispose in class without external references?

Tags: c#, dispose

I have small helper classes. The classes are used internally to make sure that certain types of string always have the appropriate format (mail addresses, phone numbers, ids, urls, keys, colors, ...).

I wanted to put them into using blocks, to be able to recycle variable names:

```
using(Id id = ids.First())
{
    Container container = containers.getById(id);
    ...
}
foreach(Id id in ids.Skip(1))
{
    Container container = containers.getById(id);
    ...
}
```

As I did this, Visual Studio asked me to mark these classes as `Disposable`, which I did, but I am not sure what to do with the method stub. Let's take a "Mail Address" class as an example:

```
public class MailAddress : IEquatable<MailAddress>, IDisposable
{
    const string MAILADDRESSPATTERN = ...
    protected string _address;
    public MailAddress(string address)
    {
        if (address == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("address");
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(address, MAILADDRESSPATTERN)) throw new ArgumentException("address");
        this._address = address.ToLower();
    }

    bool IEquatable<MailAddress>.Equals(MailAddress other)
    ...
    public override int GetHashCode()
    ...
    ...
    ...
    public override string ToString()
    ...

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

What exactly would the `Dispose` function have to do in such a class? What do I have to dispose of, and what would the Garbage Collector do automatically?

Up to now, I didn't call `Dispose` on that class anywhere, and it seemed to work fine. Now, that the class is `Disposable`, do I have to add calls to `Dispose` throughout the code?

Comment: If your class doesn't use unmanaged resources there is no use for `IDisposable`.

Comment: The garbage collector handles only managed resources. You only need to implement IDisposable your class is using unmanaged resources such as com objects. The using statement handles the call to dispose for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Dispose` method has no purpose at all since you don't seem to have any unmanaged resources. `Dispose` is only useful in the case you want to manually dispose those resources.

All managed resources are garbage-collected by the GC, so no need for any action on your side. Removing the `IDisposable` on your class seems to be the appropriate action. That would require to remove the useless `using` too, which you can exchange for simple brackets:

```
{
    Id id = ids.First();
    Container container = containers.getById(id);
    ...
}
```

Comment: To be more precise `Dispose` makes sense for managed objects too: `Dispose` method releases managed objects that consume large amounts of memory or consume scarce resources  faster than if they were reclaimed non-deterministically by the garbage collector. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @PatrickHofman To say "Dispose is only useful in the case you want to manually dispose unmanaged resources" is incorrect and misleading.  It is reasonably rare these days to implement a wrapper around unmanaged resources.  More often than not IDisposable is implemented to control timely release of managed resources E.g MySocket.Dispose controls timely release of the managed underlying Socket so user can control WHEN (not IF) the port is closed.

Answer (score 6):

Don't do this, you are abusing the language and the `Disposable` interface / pattern.

`IDisposable` is there for very specific reasons, among which are deterministic release of unmanaged resources or when your class owns disposable references.

It is most certainly not a means to create local scope so you can reuse variable names. If you need to do that simply do:

```
{
    Id id = ids.First())
    Container container = containers.getById(id);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why is he abusing the language?

Comment: Yeah okay, got what you mean. Simple brackets would have done the job too.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler forces you to implement the `IDiposable` interface in your `Id` class, because you use it with `using`. The sole and only purpose of `using` is to call `IDisposable.Dispose` after you leave its block. So you can only use it on `IDisposable` implementations.

The purpose of the `IDisposable` is to clean up external resources when the object is not used anymore. That includes closing files, disconneting from databases, returning windows handles and much, much more.

Since you don't seem to have anthing to clean up, you have no need for the `using`statement. In those cases when you *have* to use `using` (for example you are using one method for different types of objects where some have external resources), you still have to implement the `Dispose` method to satisfy the interface, but you can leave it empty.

If your class is disposable, you indeed should dispose it whenever you don't need it anymore, even if `Dispose` does nothing. If you or someone else adds cleanup code to `Dispose` later, you should rely on it being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are using the `using` keyword. The `using` keyword guaratees a call to `Dispose()` when the execution leaves the scope of the `using`. The object inside the `using` brackets is therefore required to be an `IDisposable`. If you don't have any resources you need to clean up, there is no need to wrap your object in a `using`. Since it is not a great idea to use destructors in .net, the logic you would put in a destructor is often placed in the `Dispose()` method. This allows controlled resource management when combined with the `using` keyword.